# got confused with the structure of this sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I've been reading this movie review.
Here is the link from the
[NewYorker](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/the-front-row/green-book-reviewed-peter-farrellys-bland-regressive-flip-on-driving-miss-daisy).
The part which confuses me is

- This fact renders him essentially neutered in the presence of Tony and his family and friends, as if removing from the story any racist questions of menacing black male sexuality of the sort that are planted early in the tale and then never explored or challenged.

When the author writes "as if removing from"，what is removed from what？Does it mean "the story is removed from any racist questions"？
As to "……then never explored or challenged"，which part is the subject of those verbs？

Answer (score 1):

> When the author writes "as if removing from"，what is removed from
> what？

Racist questions are removed from the story.